# Is it possible to clear the contents of a custom view in graphics memory when not displayed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a large number of custom views (all the same class) in a scroll view and I'm frequently getting memory warnings. Is it possible to somehow only allow a view to draw when it's about to be displayed and then release that view when it's no longer being displayed (i.e. it's been scrolled past) to reduce memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce the memory usage of views within a scroll view a better approach consist to define a set of views and reuse them during the scrolling process by putting them in a queue. This requires some work. I don't know how you want to layout your views but if it is a in a grid you can find some third parties libraries that does just that. One of the most famous one is called [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) it worth taking a look to understand how the views are being queued.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid using something like GMGridView because I have to do animation from within the scroll view but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I think putting in place a caching mechanism and adding animation are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to solve this issue by removing all the unneeded sub views when one sub view was selected to be viewed in full and then adding them again afterwards because this isn't a hugely costly process.